# Force use Sun Studio to compile (instead of cc) in ./configure under Solaris Sparc 11

Tags: compiler-errors, openssl, solaris, sunstudio

I want Compile OpenSSl 1.0.2a.
How to Force use Sun Studio to compile (instead of cc) in ./configure under Solaris Sparc 11. What changes need to be done in config file? I have Solaris studio 12.3 installed.When i run config file, it Configured for solaris-sparcv9-cc.

Comment: Related to *"What changes need to be done in config file"*, see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki. But I think Andrew answered your question by `export CC=...`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already invoking `cc`, Change your PATH envval so Solaris Studio's `bin` directory comes before the directory where GNU cc is locatated, probably something like this:

```
PATH=/opt/solaris_studio12.3/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

You might also need to set `CC=cc` for your `configure` to use Solaris Studio instead of `gcc`.